# Create a social authentication functionality with google django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Hello I am a newbie and have a task to do,I have tried simple social authentication that is working but below is bit complicated:

```
Create a social authentication functionality with google and add user in a
database. After adding user in a database, customer should also be created
using django signals.
Note:- Customer is one to one related with user?
```

My **models.py** :

```
class Buddy(models.Model): 
    user_name=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True) 

    def __str__(self): 
        return str(self.user_name) 


class Customer(models.Model): 
    customer_name=models.OneToOneField(Buddy,
                                       on_delete = models.CASCADE,
                                       blank=True,null=True) 
    def __str__(self): 
         return str(self.customer_name)
```

My **settings.py** includes the following lines:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = '2377[...].apps.googleusercontent.com' 
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = '[...]' 
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE = ['email'] 
INSTALLED_APPS = [ ... # oauth 
                  'oauth2_provider', 
                  'social_django', 
                  'rest_framework_social_oauth2' ] 

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ( # Google OAuth2 
   'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2', 
    # django-rest-framework-social-oauth2                            
   'rest_framework_social_oauth2.backends.DjangoOAuth2', # Django 
   'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', )
```

Comment: What you've tried so far? Show us some code to begin with.

Comment: class Buddy(models.Model):
    user_name=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user_name)

class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_name=models.OneToOneField(Buddy,on_delete = models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.customer_name)

Comment: SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = '2377[...].apps.googleusercontent.com'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = '[...]'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE = ['email']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    # oauth
    'oauth2_provider',
    'social_django',
    'rest_framework_social_oauth2'
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Google OAuth2
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',

    # django-rest-framework-social-oauth2
    'rest_framework_social_oauth2.backends.DjangoOAuth2',

    # Django
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

Comment: i am unable to handle the views

Comment: i have tried to redirect through direct html page,but this is to be done using api

Comment: @Ashu please move the **Django** code from your comments into the question's body so others will be able to read it.

Comment: So you have to define your custom **Django** **signal** which you'll be able *to* *emit* - look at [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/), then you have to link your signal to a custom view in your **views.py** to trigger a callback for a specific signal, which you can define in **callbacks.py** or any other file. If you have the custom view triggering your signal please post the code here. Django Signals implement observer pattern.

Comment: You have to create your **Buddy** in your custom view in your **views.py** and once saved in database via Django ORM - emit your signal to create the **Customer** using **Django ORM** in your callback.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Django's **post_save** signal.

In your **models.py** have:

```
class Buddy(models.Model): 
    user_name=models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True) 

    def __str__(self): 
        return str(self.user_name) 


class Customer(models.Model): 
    # This translates into buddy_id when you migrate
    buddy=models.OneToOneField(Buddy,on_delete = models.CASCADE,
                               blank=True, null=True) 
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True) 

    def __str__(self): 
        return str(self.customer_name)
```

In your **views.py** make sure you have

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from .models import Buddy
from .callbacks import save_customer

# You'll customize this view to read any parameters and provide user_name
def custom_view(request):
     Buddy.objects.create(user_name="SomeUsername")
     # Any of your other logic comes here, specify in the dict 
     return render(request, 'yourpage.html', {})


# This should be at the bottom of your views.py:
post_save.connect(save_customer, sender=Buddy)
```

Then create a new file in the same location called **callbacks.py** and there include:

```
from .models import Buddy
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Buddy)
def save_customer(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Customize your OneOnOne model on a meaningful way so it will be useful
    customer = Customer.objects.create(customer_name=instance.user_name) 
    instance.customer = customer
    instance.customer.save()
```

Read more about Django signals [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/).